# scheduling a script that accepts one argument in crontab

Tags: linux, crontab

i am trying to schedule a shell script that runs for every 10 mins, and the script accepts some argument.. i have done it like this

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * sh /home/vpnuser/VPN_BL_GUI/VpnJboss/bin/bulkCommands.sh 22468 > /home/vpnuser/VPN_BL_GUI/VpnJboss/bin/waste.txt
```

but seems not to be working, but the file waste.txt is generation empty for every 10 mins. but the actual script is not running. please help

i have tried googling, but no use.. all forums give me the answer how i have pasted above.. its not working for me.. please help.

Comment: Are you running it with `vpnuser`. Does your user can write in `/home/vpnuser/VPN_BL_GUI/VpnJboss/bin/waste.txt` ? Can your user read /home/vpnuser/VPN_BL_GUI/VpnJboss/bin/bulkCommands.sh ?

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, check the `cron` log to make sure your script is executed (I assume it is not a global `crontab` because in that case you are missing the username for the user to run the script)
- Then try running your command in it's entirety using `sudo` (again, assuming you plan to run it as root (it could be that the target directory is missing or not permissioned for writing files).
- Finally, replace `> ...` with `>> /home/vpnuser/VPN_BL_GUI/VpnJboss/bin/waste.txt 2>&1` to keep the output for future analysis.

Comment: hi Alexander, where can i check the cronlogs??

Comment: Or remove the redirection altogether and see what you get in your email.

Comment: Email?? i have not configured anything like that triplee.. may i get an explanation please??

Comment: Cron logs' location depends on your OS. Typically it in `/var/log/cron` or `var/log/messages`. As for email from `cron` this is tricky. On many current systems it is difficult to track down the destination of `cron` e-mail output (i.e. it does not necessarily end up in root's inbox).

Comment: @alexander and tripleee, this is wat i have i my Email, "TERM environment variable not set.
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
/home/vpnuser/VPN_BL_GUI/VpnJboss/bin/bulkCommands.sh: line 20: jmap: command not found
"

Comment: i have this line in my script jmap -dump:file=my_stack$RANDOM.bin $1

Comment: Run your script manually as described above (as the user you intend to run it as) and fix any errors that might show. This will fix your issue.

Comment: If the script works correctly when you run it manually, you may have a problem with PATH not being set correctly in the cron job.